# Separate button:active from parentDiv:Active

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to have a button within a div. When the Button is pressed the box-shadow of the button disappears and when the parent-div is pressed it's box-shadow should disappear too.

The problem is when I press the button the shadow of the parent div disappears too which shouldn't be

For example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.parent {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 @color;
   //some styling

    button {
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 @color;
    }

    button:active{
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}

.parent:active{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

How can the separation be achieved? 
I am using less and tried so far changing z-index.

What came to my mind is if it is possible to reapply the box-shadow if both classes are active but I do not know if that is possible and if so how the selector looks like.

I prefer a none js solution which is purely based on css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And idea is to use another element to create the shadow. It will be a sibling of the button and you will no more have issue:

```css
.parent {
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.parent .shadow  {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 red;
}

button {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.parent .shadow:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>a title</h1>
  <p>some text</p>
  <button>a button</button>
  <span class="shadow"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you its working, yet is there another way to expand the span over the full parent-div other than position absolute?

Comment: @x3lq i don't think so, as the idea is to create a layer above the whole div to create the shadow and to get the click, So I don't think there is something else we can do